# Joomla 2.5 switching style sheets

Tags: php, joomla

I have just updated a site to Joomla 2.5 and have an issue I hope someone can help with. In my templateDetails.xml file I have some paramater set up to switch styles on certain areas of my site.

```
<config>
 <fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="advanced">
        <field name="templateColor" type="list" default="blue" label="TPL_ECRMEURO_TEMPLATE_COLOR" description="" filter="word">
        <option value="blue">TPL_ECRMEURO_TEMPLATE_COLOR_BLUE</option>
        <option value="green">TPL_ECRMEURO_TEMPLATE_COLOR_GREEN</option>
        <option value="red">TPL_ECRMEURO_TEMPLATE_COLOR_RED</option>
        <option value="purple">TPL_ECRMEURO_TEMPLATE_COLOR_PURPLE</option>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

In my index.php I have also set up the head area withe the correct paramaters? as below

```
<?php
/**
 * @subpackage  Templates.ecrmeuro
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2011 Aurora Consulting All rights reserved.
 */

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/* Template variables */
$templateColor = $this->params->get('templateColor');

// get params
$app      = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc      = JFactory::getDocument();
$templateparams  = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;
$defaultMenu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getDefault()->id;
$currentMenu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->id;

if($defaultMenu == $currentMenu){ 
   $bodyId = 'id="home"'; 
   $homePage = true; 
}else{
   $bodyId = ''; 
   $homePage = false; 
}
?>
```

All was working great in 1.7 until I upgraded. In Joomla 2.5 I can still assign the style to menu items however no changes happen. Can anyone help or know if there has been any changes in the way additional template styles are assigned to pages in 2.5 as cannot seem to identify this issue..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Have you tried cleaning browser cache? Also, see [Potential backward compatibility issues](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_2.5_and_Joomla_Platform_11.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally solved I forgot to add a reference to the stylesheet and pull in onto the template. All working great again.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/<?php echo $this->params->get( 'templateColor' ) ?><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pageclass) ?>.css" type="text/css"/>
```

The above formats and pulls in the Base URL to the Template folder, The CSS folder, the template blue in this case and finally the suffix .css